# No consigi subir archivos al gitt

Tags: linux, git

soy nuevo en Git y tengo un problema. Intento subir archivos al repositorio Git con los comandos "git add, git commit,git push". Cuando ejecuto git ls-files, veo todos los archivos en la lista, pero cuando un compañero descarga mi repositorio e intenta acceder, aparece vacío. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo y lograr que los archivos se suban y sean visibles?

Comment: Revisa la rama en la que empujaste.... y verifica que en el repositorio remoto, dicha rama tenga lo que empujaste,

Comment: para añadir todos los elementos modificados a tu commit, según yo era `git add .`, y en git push debe devolverte un mensaje de que se subió correctamente, no te da ningún error? igual y es buena práctica hacer un `git pull`  antes de hacer un push, por temas de que haya conflictos en merge.

Comment: Lo raro es que no me aparece ningún error al hacer git push

Comment: Preguntas a resolver: ¿Cómo verificas la rama a la que has hecho `git push` ? ¿El colega está usando la misma rama? ¿Cómo verificas que así sea?

Comment: Eh verificado la rema y los 2 tenemos la rama  origin/master